# convert dos2unix line endings for all files in a directory

Tags: sed, awk

Currently, I am using the following command to change dos2unix line endings, but this is for file-y file...

```
sed -i 's/\r//' filename
```

Is there a way to run this command for all the files in a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in `find . -type f \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" \)`; do    sed -i 's/\r//' $i ; done
```

Comment: Please don't perpetuate [this horrendous practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) errors like this. This WILL fail for files with special characters, and could potentially be harmful to your system. If you want recursion, and you're using bash, use `globstar`. If you don't use bash, use `find ... -exec`. But not this, *please*.

Answer (score 46):

The simplest way to run `dos2unix` against an entire directory recursively is to just have the `find` command execute it for each file it finds based on your criteria.

For example, to find all files (excluding directory names) in your current directory and all its sub-directories and have `dos2unix` do the default conversion on each of those files:

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix -k -s -o {} ';'
```

This will output every single filename, but not necessarily change each of them. This works as follows:

`find .`: Find anything in this directory, including its subdirectories, and anything in those subdirectories as well (recursion)
`-type f`: Only return 'regular file' names. Exclude folder names from the results.
`-exec`: Execute the following command for every result. Everything beyond this point should be treated as part of that command until the `;` character is found.
`dos2unix`: `dos2unix` will be executed with the following options...
`-k`: Keep the date stamp of the output file the same as the input file
`-s`: Skip binary files (images, archives, etc.). This option is included by default, but I use it anyway in case that default were different on some systems (e.g. OS X v. Debian v. CentOS v. Ubuntu v. ...).
`-o`: Write the changes directly to the file, rather than creating a new file with the data in the new format.
`{}`: This tells `find` to insert the filename it has found as a parameter of the `dos2unix` call.
`';'`: Tell `find` that the params for `dos2unix` have ended. Anything beyond this point will again be treated as a parameter of `find`.

Comment: +1 for the thorough explanation of all the command line options

Comment: A word of caution: be VERY careful to ensure there is no .git located somewhere down the directory, as it could have objects with Windows line endings in it (if you committed them, for example). It can easily corrupt a git directory as the shas of the files will no longer match up.

Answer (score 6):

Simple:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' filename1 filename2 … filenameN
```

or, if you are speaking about content of one directory

```
sed -i 's/\r//' *
```

Work just well for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
dos2unix *.txt
```

works fine to convert all *.txt files in a directory... no need for the 'find' command.

Comment: Yes but it's not recursive.

Answer (score 2):

Another option: `find your_dir type f -exec sed -i 's/\r//' {} \;`

Why aren't you using dos2unix command? If your'e doing just the sed above there might be files (depending on their source) that will have incorrect EOF (you can see it if you run cat and the prompt afterwards is concatenated to the file output)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another reference ...

On Ubuntu 14.04 the `man dos2unix` page provides this example, specifically for recusive conversion:

`find . -name *.txt | xargs dos2unix`

Quoting from the man page, this will

> ... convert all the .txt files in the directory tree under the current
>   directory ...

Answer (score 0):

```
find $(pwd) -type f | xargs -I xxx sed -i 's/\r//g' xxx
```